# retrieving the path of an ImageIcon

Tags: java, netbeans, jlabel, imageicon

I have a jlabel that has already an icon, and i want to change the icon when i exit the mouse from the label, i tried this code, it shows no syntax error

```
private void LabelMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   

if(Label.getIcon().toString().equals("cyberjayacinema/images/Blue%20E1"))
    {
        Label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cyberjayacinema/images/red E1.PNG")));
    }

else
    {
            Label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cyberjayacinema/images/white E1.PNG")));
    }
```

but only the **else** case works, although the **imageicon** is set to the **if** case, so i guess the error is with retrieving the path of the icon, i assume the way i wrote my **getImageIcon** was wrong, 
I wish someone can help me with this.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just put a `System.out.println(label.getIcon().toString())`, you will get something like, this

```
file:/C:/NetBeansProjects/StackOverflow/build/classes/resources/stackoverflow5.png
```

As you can see, that will not match your case.

You may want to do something like this, to get just the file name

```
String iconfilename = label.getIcon().toString();
String fileName = iconfilename.substring(iconfilename.lastIndexOf("/"  ) + 1);
System.out.println(fileName);

// output
stackoverflow5.png
```

Then just check against the file name.

```
if ("stackoverflow5.png".equals(fileName)) {
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you if you are trying to access image from your project folder

```
 Lable test;
java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("res/image.png");
test.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url));
```

Comment: can you please explain to me how can i use this in my case? because i'm still beginner, and i didn't really understand the code.